# Does email you send or reply to contain privacy information that spammers could use?

Tags: email, privacy, smtp

I have received a few emails recently that seem like spam but they are asking about open source projects I've worked on and gmail didn't flag them as spam.

When I email or reply to an email does privacy related data get sent with my email? I've looked at the headers and there's a lot of information in there.

Regarding the red flags, the email doesn't match the name, spelling errors, the questions make no sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your outbound emails won't contain much personal information, but there are some things to be aware of:

- Replying confirms to a spammer that your address is active, so you'll get **significantly** more spam
- Email services often append your display name, which may be your real name, like `John Smith <js1234@domain.com>`
- The recipient is able to see every email server the email passed through, and may be able to discern your approximate region when using cloud services like gmail.
- If you're using a corporate email template or signature, then you are basically providing a spammer with your company's letterhead.

Don't reply to obvious spam, and the same goes for auto-replies to untrusted addresses.

---

https://kinsta.com/blog/email-header/

https://mailtrap.io/blog/email-headers/

Answer (score 2):

If you are forwarding your email (or using a catchall), there is a chance that replying will expose some headers that would be super-useful to spammers/scammers.

e.g. `X-Resolved-to:` and `X-Delivered-to`:

Whether or not that reveals privacy information will depend on your use case (e.g. you forward mail to `mailbox@[YOUR REAL NAME].com` or `[FIRST].[LAST].[YEAR OF BIRTH]@gmail.com`).

Answer (score 1):

As others said the outbound messages won't include much personal data but:

- Responding verifies your email's activity to a spammer, thereby increasing your [volume of spam](https://www.mailslurp.com/guides/virus-and-spam-detection/) considerably. Best not to reply.
- Your name might be exposed
- Your company signature could be revealed which might include sensitive data

Comment: Hi, this site is not run like a forum, so each answer is expected to be unique.  And none of this is.

Comment: Fair enough! Will try improve answer in future